# Matlab Query: How to align 'title' at the botton of the figure when plotting points

Tags: matlab, plot, title

My question says everything. I am plotting points on Matlab. But when I set 'title' value, it displays title-name at the top of the image by default. How can I get the title set a the bottom of the image?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't use `xlabel` you could use that as a quick hack.

If you do use the `xlabel`, add another line or two by passing a cell array:

```
figure;
xlabel({'X-label', '', 'Figure title'});
```

As Amro mentioned in his comments you can make a text anywhere with `uicontrol`:

```
x=linspace(0,10*pi);
plot3(x,x.*cos(x),x.*sin(x)); % Plot a 3d spiral
uicontrol('Style','text','Position', [200 20 200 20],'String','My Title')
```

The positioning is not automatic, so when you resize the figure, the title will move away from the center.

Comment: Hi Kleist, thank you very much.  It worked without any problem for the 2D plot. But how can I get the same thing for the MESH Diagram?? In such diagram, it shows below the X-axis and not at the center of the image.. Any idea?

Comment: You can always position a text manually, but then it would probably not behave correctly when zooming, panning, etc.

Comment: Added example of manual positioning. It works when zooming and panning, but not when resizing.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to move the x-axis on top, and bring the title to bottom:

```
plot(rand(10,1))
h = xlabel('');     pos = get(h,'Position'); delete(h)
h = title('title'); set(h,'Position',pos);
set(gca, 'XAxisLocation','top')
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi Amro, thanks for your reply. But your X-axis got shifted to the top of the image which is not actually what i want. Keeping X and Y axis at their original location, I just want the title to be displayed at the bottom of the image. Now can you suggest me some way??

Comment: @user990479: you could always use [UICONTROL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol.html) to add a static text component to your GUI at the desired location